# addEventListener not work for onmousemove

Tags: javascript, html, dom

here is my code

HTML

```
<body>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="id">
    <p></p>
</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
body{
display: flex; 
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 500px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("id").addEventListener("click", func);
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("onmousemove", func);

function func() {
    console.log(5)
}
```

addEventListener work for "click" event but not work for "onmousemove"

Comment: There is no "onmousemove" event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event

Comment: Because, when you use `addEventListener`, you don't have to write `on` before events. The correct way is this: `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('mousemove', func)`

Comment: @DiegoSaravia why that is? and where can i find about it on internet!?

Comment: @DiegoSaravia why that is? and where can i find about it on internet!?

Comment: @sMohammad14 it's something I learned on the road. Every event that has `on` at the beginning of its name (in html, like `onclick` and so on), when you write the listener on JavaScript, you write the name without the `on`.
You can read the events tha exists in this page: https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=842:lista-de-eventos-javascript-on-click-dblclick-mouseover-mouseout-change-submit-keypress-cu01159e&catid=78&Itemid=206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("id").addEventListener("click", func);
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].addEventListener("mousemove", func);

function func() {
    console.log(5)
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="id">This is the div to hover at</div>
</body>
```

The [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event) event is fired at an element when a pointing device (usually a mouse) is moved while the cursor's hotspot is inside it.

So you should be doing

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('mousemove', func)
```